# How to cancel Spark Hadoop RDD computation

Tags: java, scala, hadoop, apache-spark, cluster-computing

Let say I have `NewHadoopRDD` and one of its split fails during computation. Having local runner I easily see all stages of this process.

I see task failure but scheduler starts next task and only after this notices task failure.

```
15/02/19 20:58:58 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Starting task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1, localhost, PROCESS_LOCAL, 1347 bytes)
15/02/19 20:58:58 INFO executor.Executor: Running task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1)
15/02/19 20:58:58 WARN scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost): java.lang.RuntimeException: java.sql.SQLException:
```

...

```
15/02/19 20:58:58 ERROR scheduler.TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
```

Now stage is being cancelled

```
15/02/19 20:58:58 ERROR scheduler.TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
15/02/19 20:58:58 INFO scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl: Cancelling stage 0 
15/02/19 20:58:58 INFO executor.Executor: Executor is trying to kill task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1)
15/02/19 20:58:58 INFO scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl: Stage 0 was cancelled
```

And control even passes to context close...

```
15/02/19 20:58:58 INFO ui.SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at http://node4.hbase.vitech.com.ua:4040
```

But then I see log output from next stage task.

```
15/02/19 20:58:58 INFO rdd.NewHadoopRDD: Input split: 0+0 ...
```

And only on scheduler stop I see task is killed (on statusUpdate!).

```
15/02/19 20:58:58 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Stopping DAGScheduler
15/02/19 20:58:58 INFO executor.Executor: Executor killed task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1)
15/02/19 20:58:58 ERROR scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl: Exception in statusUpdate
```

Can I do something to cleanup all RDD resources faster? `unpersist()` does not help here. I see it's log before context stop logging. But anyway I see then next task logs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No way to recover faster. Once a task has been started it will either finish or fail on its own. The stage failure or cancellation will not interrupt an in-progress task.

I think the reason is that basically [threads cannot be forcefully killed in Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/misc/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html). If this is a problem, you could go for more partitions. Smaller tasks finish faster.

Comment: Sad but true. I have came to the same answer.